# Compare lists and dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My query is to fetch each item in the list compare with the key of the dictionary and fetch its value.

Code:

```
for each_element in list1:
   for key,value in my_dictionary.items():
       if each_element == key:
          output = value
```

The error I am facing is the element from the list is:

```
list element: ['a','b']
key from dictionary: 'a,b'
```

which is not matching. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: First snippet is not a valid Python code... And `a,b == ["a", "b"]` is false, why should it match? String can never be equal to list, why should it be? `a,b == ','.join(['a', 'b'])` may be true, but since you are not doing this conversion yourself, why Python should guess that's what you want?

Comment: @Rogalski, actually it is a python code but jus a test snippet and could you pl explain what i am doing wrong more clearly

Comment: I have no idea why you are using a loop to look up items in a dictionary. Perhaps consult [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: @SurajDavey you seem to not understand what `dict` is. It is a hash table. That means you can search for keys like `d[key]`.

Comment: @CPanda I get that, but still  not able to hash it because of difference mentioned in my question.

Comment: @SurajDavey I have posted an answer. Check.

Comment: @Suraj Davey: to make question clear you need to provide content of list1 and my_dictionary.

For example, if list1 = ['a', 'b'] and my_dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':2} then your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

give try-except a shot and bypass any mismatches without generating an error. Use the search functionality of dictionaries - myDictionary[KeyToSearchFor] ouputs the value, if any.

```
L = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
D = {'a':10,'b':20,'c':30,'d':40,'z':50,'f':60, 'g':70}

for i in L:
    try:
        print("key: {} / value: {}".format(i,D[i]))
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

output, notice no match on 'e'

```
key: a / value: 10
key: b / value: 20
key: c / value: 30
key: d / value: 40
key: f / value: 60
```

Comment: Note - it's generally not a good idea to have a generic `except` statement, as it can mask over other problems in the code.

Comment: I do agree but you could certainly expand it so that it doesn't mask other problems. But yes...you are 100% correct sir

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your list being `[["a","b"],..]` and dictionary being `{"a,b":val1,...}`

```
out = (my_dict.get(",".join(item)) for item in my_list)
# out := [val1, val2, None, None, val3..], None for non-existent keys
# to weed out None vals
out2 = (item for item in out if item)
# and finally, consume the iterator
output = list(out2)
```